# An error of SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, "failed to retrieve ProductVersions for package"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I try to uninstall SQL Server 2008 R2 enterprise and I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Did you try restarting Windows?

Comment: Yes, I did. And I stil get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your registry entries. Got to RegEdit and search for **76C3ED27** (that is the reverse of your product code).

Export your registry and delete the registry entry for the product Code.You can now install your application.

Comment: No worries. Help me out someday.